# Django with mod_wsgi on apache - 500 error: Authtype not set?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Trying to deploy my first django site on Dreamhost...I had this working and then I'm not sure what I did to make it stop working.

This is the error message:

```
[crit] [client 74.72.99.26] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /internal_error.html

<VirtualHost :80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/mysite.com/dir/project/wsgi.py
<Directory /home/username/mysite.com/dir/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can also include my wsgi.py info but I don't think it's the problem because like I said I had the site working. Not sure if this is relevant or not but I was also trying to password protect my domain(I did that in my dreamhost panel) so that people can't see my site as I'm trying to deploy it - that is the only authentication I can think of that might be causing this, but I took the password protection off and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem with Apache v 2.2 (Ubuntu). From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files):

"If you are using a version of Apache older than 2.4, replace `Require all granted` with `Allow from all`"

... and that fixed it.

Comment: You really save me. But after change this, i get this:  ```[error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=13569): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'mysite.com' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.13565.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts. ```