# Apache: "AuthType not set!" 500 Error

Tags: apache

It's been a while since I used the Apache httpd web server.  I'm firing up a local server for a project and when I try to request localhost/index.html, I get a 500 error and I see this in the error log:

```
[Tue Jan 21 09:23:58 2014] [crit] [client ::1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /index.html
[Tue Jan 21 09:23:58 2014] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
[Tue Jan 21 09:23:58 2014] [crit] [client ::1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /favicon.ico
```

It looks like there are possibly 2 errors here in the apache config, one related to "AuthType not set!" and possibly another related to "filter was not added: DEFLATE".  I dont know what these means or where to start digging in.

A basic Google search revealed [this link](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=8603) which indicates that the culprit may be "Require all granted".  This line in my httpd.conf may be involved.

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This apache config is mostly what is used in production for this project, so I know this works, just not currently on my workstation.  What does this mean and what should I try next?  I did try commenting out "Require all granted" and restarting apache but to no avail.

Following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064060/django-with-mod-wsgi-on-apache-500-error-authtype-not-set) I also loaded mod_authz_host

```
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

and added "Allow from all", restarted the server,. but the issue persists.  The deflate issue appears to be unrelated, and was easily solved by adding

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

The question remains, how do I solve this 500 error?

```
[Tue Jan 21 09:44:20 2014] [crit] [client ::1] 
configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. 
AuthType not set!: /index.html
```

Answer (score 187):

Remove the line that says

```
Require all granted
```

it's only needed on Apache >=2.4

Comment: Or alternatively use the <IfVersion> syntax...see my answer below.

Comment: In OS X MAMP apache 2.2, change from "Require all granted" to Satisfy Any

Answer (score 51):

The problem here can be formulated another way: how do I make a config that works both in apache 2.2 and 2.4?

`Require all granted` is only in 2.4, but `Allow all ...` stops working in 2.4, and we want to be able to rollout a config that works in both.

The only solution I found, which I am not sure is the proper one, is to use:

```
# backwards compatibility with apache 2.2
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

# forward compatibility with apache 2.4
Require all granted
Satisfy Any
```

This should resolve your problem, or at least did for me. Now the problem will probably be much harder to solve if you have more complex access rules...

See also [this fairly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641646/how-to-accomplish-authtype-none-in-apache-2-2). The Debian wiki also has [useful instructions for supporting both 2.2 and 2.4](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache/PackagingFor24#Making_web_applications_compatible_to_both.2C_Apache_2.2_and_2.4).

Comment: i purposefully *joined* the two snippets so they work in *both* versions here, please do not separate them again.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Alternatively, this solution works with both Apache2 version < 2.4 as well as >= 2.4. Make sure that the "version" module is enabled:

```
a2enmod version
```

And then use this code instead:

```
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
```

Comment: You can also go with this answer to avoid activating another module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707186/detect-apache-version-in-apache-config

Answer (score 3):

Just remove/comment the following line from your httpd.conf file (etc/httpd/conf)

Require all granted

This is needed till Apache Version 2.2 and is not required from thereon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a version 2.4.x of Apache.

Have you sure that you load this 2 modules ?
 - mod_authn_core
 - mod_authz_core

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

PS : My recommendation for authorization and rights is (by default) :

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
```

Comment: Thanks Georgio, actually I don't have the auth{n|z}_core modules in my modules directory.

Comment: You see these modules all the same with `httpd -l` ?

Comment: I wonder, should I build those separately?  This is the out of the box installation of 2.2.15 on CentOS ` apachectl -version
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 13 2013 17:29:28`

Comment: Arf, sorry, you use Apache 2.2.x and not 2.4.x. Modules have no same name. The modules is :   mod_authn_file.c
  mod_authn_default
  mod_authz_host
  mod_authz_groupfile
  mod_authz_user
  mod_authz_default
  mod_auth_basic

Comment: Cool, thanks for the list, I added all of them and restarted but am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` if you use it in your config.