# How to enable a directory listing in Apache web server

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am not able to enable directory listing in my Apache web server. I have tried various solutions posted, but it is not working. I just freshly installed httpd 2.4.6 and enabled HTTPS using *ssl.conf* under the */etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf* directory and trying to access https://server.example.com/, but this is not listing the directory. These are the configuration in file *ssl.conf*:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/userx/Downloads/"
ServerName server.example.com:443
```

Below is what it has in *ssl.conf* under the VirtualHost element. Files and the first *Directory* elements were already there when I installed, and I just added *Directory* for "/home/userx/Downloads". I want to browse the contents of */home/userx/Downloads* when I access the URL *https://server.example.com/*. What am I missing here?

```
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/userx/Downloads">
  Options +Indexes
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 30):

See if you are able to access/list the '/icons/' directory. This is useful to test the behavior of "Directory" in Apache.

For example: You might be having the below configuration by default in your *httpd.conf* file. So hit the URL *IP:Port/icons/* and see if it lists the icons or not. You can also try by putting the 'directory/folder' inside the 'var/www/icons'.

```
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If it does work, then you can cross-check or modify your custom directory configuration with the '<Directory "/var/www/icons">' configuration.

Comment: If you get an `AuthType` error then remove the line `Require all granted` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265191/apache-authtype-not-set-500-error)

Answer (score 16):

According to the Apache documentation, [found here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings), the `DirectoryIndex` directive needs to be specified in the site `.conf` file (typically found in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` on Linux).

Quoting from the documentation, it reads:

> If no file from the `DirectoryIndex` directive can be located in the
> directory, then mod_autoindex can generate a listing of the directory
> contents. This is turned on and off using the `Options` directive. For
> example, to turn on directory listings for a particular directory, you
> can use:
>
> ```
> <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/listme>
>   Options +Indexes
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> To prevent directory listings (for security purposes, for example),
> you should remove the Indexes keyword from every Options directive in
> your configuration file. Or to prevent them only for a single
> directory, you can use:
>
> ```
> <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/dontlistme>
>   Options -Indexes
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: very useful answer.. finally it is working!

Comment: Your citation doesn't even say it has to be specified, let alone in the `.conf` file. It can also be specified in local `.htaccess` files, and it can be completely omitted.

Comment: yes, that was helpful for me.  Placing `Options +Indexes` in .htaccess file will enable file and directory listing on per folder basis. Do not use <Directory> tag within .htaccess file

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
<Directory "/home/userx/Downloads">
  Options +Indexes
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny 
  Allow from all 
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If that doesn't work, you probably have 'deny indexes' somewhere that's overriding your config.

Comment: Still does not work after changing to your suggestion and restarting the server. Logs show this:

[Tue Aug 30 18:40:46.492983 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20665] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 171.71.229.25:59061] AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied
[Tue Aug 30 18:40:46.493000 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20665] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 171.71.229.25:59061] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied

Comment: Ah, okay. I forget that Apache 2.4 needs a require all granted. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Event that does not help. May be I am having some basic issue, because with DocumentRoot "/home/userx/Downloads/", I created a test dir within that and one index.html file in that test dir but accessing https://server.example.com/test/index.html is also not allowed.

 [pid 21402] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 171.71.229.25:59498] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Aug 30 18:55:38.108746 2016] [core:error] [pid 21402] (13)Permission denied: [client 171.71.229.25:59498] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /home/sburnwal/Downloads/test/index.html

Comment: For testing, chmod the index.html to 775. Is it allowed after that?

Comment: I had done chmod 755 to index.html but no luck yet. I had also ensured chmod 755 unto / dir

Comment: Is there any log that would say what deny rules the server executed ? or anyway to enabled such logs ? I want to know how it is deciding deny access.

Comment: and chmod -R 775 to the directory you created?

Comment: I don't know of a device to analyze the allow/deny rules :/

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by enabling the `mod_autoindex` from Apache. It was disabled by default.

```
sudo a2enmod autoindex
```

Comment: How did you enable it ?

Comment: `sudo a2enmod autoindex`

Comment: a2enmod : command not found

Comment: @Kokodoko, that's because a2enmod is a debian thing.

Answer (score 3):

This one solved my issue which is an [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) setting:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/*
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  For others, change the /home/* to your content path (in my case /var/repo/).  Since you're using -R the * probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Once I changed `Options -Index` to `Options +Index` in my conf file, I removed the welcome page and restarted services.

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

I was able to see directory listings after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable the [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) module to make this work. Note: The system needs to be rebooted for SELinux to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by creating a soft link to whichever directory you want to list in the /var/www/html/ directory.

```
sudo ln -s /home/ /var/www/html/
```

Keep in mind the security.