# How can I display a list of folders on a local webpage by only using HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

This is my first question.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is a display a list of local folders on my index.html page, however I am unsure as to how to do so. For example, let's say I have a list of music albums:

```
folder: Good Charlotte
song.mp3
folder: A Day To Remember
song2.mp3
folder: Green Day
song3.mp3
```

What I would like to do is to display each folder on the html page and then also be able to click on each one to access the files in the folders.

Thank you very much for your assistance in advance, and if you need any more details please do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. The main issue is I'm not even sure what to do, I browsed through here for an answer, couldn't find one so I ended up asking a question myself.

Comment: You need to use whatever programming language you have available on the server to read the directories and output the data or generate the html needed

Comment: So I have managed to use <a href></a> to display the files of each folder. My intention is to make it so that instead of displaying on another page, it would do it under the 'List of Songs' header. I have attached an image to give you an idea of what I am going for.

Comment: If by "local" you mean "Local to the webserver that is hosting your website" then you need to learn a server side programming language (and your questin is too broad). If you mean "Local to the computer the browser is running on", then you can't do this.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2l3nu

Comment: Using JAVA applet with local filesystem HTML file, you can list a directory. However, the browser should support JAVA. In Microsoft Windows ActiveX may do it too.

Comment: Node.js (js on the server) gives you the ability to read a directory's contents https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Comment: Don't know what you got server side, but atleast in windows you can enable folder browsing in iis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing files of a directory in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860507/listing-files-of-a-directory-in-a-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and easiest way to do this is to simply use the default files and folders listing from your webserver.

[image]

Since you are asking this question I suspect it may not be enabled. Here is how to enable it :

IIS (windows):

> appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true|false

or use the UI. See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

Apache (linux):

```
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

See here : [How to enable directory listing in apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239276/how-to-enable-directory-listing-in-apache-web-server)

**Styling the output**

I also stumbled across this webpage that teaches how to output your own way using PHP and CSS. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/

[image]

```
  <?php
    // Opens directory
    $myDirectory=opendir(".");

    // Gets each entry
    while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
      $dirArray[]=$entryName;
    }


    // Loops through the array of files
    for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
         // ...
    }
```