# How to allow sub directory files from being viewed when url is entered. Htaccess amendment

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, subdirectory

I would like to be able to view individual files and list of a sub directory by entering in the url. I have around 100 folders with images and I want to be able to click on links and see the images. I previously had this and the developer has done something to stop it!

For example my website is `example.com` and I have a folder called `2176`; I want to be able to enter `example.com/2176` and I want to view the list of files and the date the file was modified (if possible).

I have read it is just a change to the `.htaccess` file. I can post my `.htaccess` file but Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post it as it saw errors.

I tried removing the `/` after `RewriteBase`, but that didn't work

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76687006/edit) to add your (formatted) code.

Comment: "but Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post it as it saw errors" - You need to "format" your code by either intending by 4 spaces (button on the editor toolbar) or use backtick fencing (3 backticks on a line before and after the code block).

Comment: Thanks MrWhite I have inserted the snippet of my htaccess file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable a directory listing in Apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239276/how-to-enable-a-directory-listing-in-apache-web-server)

Comment: What response are you getting when requesting `example.com/2176/` (note there must be a trailing slash if `2176` is a directory). A 403, a 404, a 200 (and perhaps a blank page) or something else?

Comment: 404 Page Not Found
We're sorry, but the server could not find the URL you tried to load.

Comment: Is there another `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory?

Comment: No there is not